# Accessing array index in .net expression loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, expression, indexer

I'm currently stuck at solving the problem of building an expression tree which validates multiple arguments from an array.
But I can't use Expression.Loop to iterate through all elements of the input array. Because I don't know how to convert the count variable to int.
I tried to use ArrayAccess but its pretty complicated.
Many thanks.
Here is my code:

```
//array stores temp input. inputCount is a dynamic value that got from the argument
object[] inParams = new object[inputCount];
var breakLabel = Expression.Label("LoopBreak");
//input of parameters to pass in the expression
ParameterExpression[] param = new ParameterExpression[inputCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < inputCount; i++)
            {                
                param[i] = Expression.Parameter(inParams[i].GetType(), "randomname");
//count variable for indexer
ParameterExpression count = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "count");
            }
BlockExpression block2 = Expression.Block(
                new[] { count },
                Expression.Assign(count, Expression.Constant(0)),
                Expression.Loop(
                    Expression.IfThenElse(
                            Expression.LessThan(count, Expression.Constant(param.Count())),                            
                            Expression.Block(
//Assign param[count] element from inParams[count] element
                                Expression.Assign(param[count], Expression.Constant(inParams[count])),
                                Expression.PostIncrementAssign(count)
                                ),
                            Expression.Break(breakLabel)
                    ),
                    breakLabel
                ));
```

Comment: Would  you mind formatting your code? Its really hard to read

Comment: Unfortunately the code you have supplied contains multiple references which aren't defined e.g. ltBool, controls, breakLabel amongst others. See the notes on providing a minimal complete, verifiable, example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hm I can see the code is formatted. I also edited to remove unnecessary words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh? What is "complicated" about `Expression.ArrayAccess`? All you need is `Expression.Assign(Expression.ArrayAccess(array, index), value)`. Your problem is mixing runtime arrays with "build"time arrays.

You probably don't want to use `Expression.Loop` at all, since you need to iterate over something that isn't an array. Instead, just build a simple block of expressions:

```
Expression.Block
(
  param.Select
  (
    (item, index) =>
    Expression.Assign(item, Expression.Constant(inParams[index]))
  )
);
```

That said, I'm not sure what you're trying to do "assigning" to a parameter. Maybe you're trying to use `Expression.Variable` instead or something?